# How to generate CFI strings for .ePub files in flutter/dart

Tags: html, flutter, dart, epub

### Problem

I am trying to generate the CFI(Canonical Fragment Identifiers) for an `.ePub` file in dart.

### Enviroment

I am able to read the `.ePub` file and can access it in dart but can't seem to make heads or tales on how to generate the CFI strings for each chapter/subchapter.

I am using the `epub_view 3.0.0` package found here: https://pub.dev/packages/epub_view but i am open to using other packages if epub_view doesn't have this functionality.

### What I've tried

In a function call, I tried.

```
EpubBook epubBook = await EpubReader.readBook(epubFile.readAsBytes());

EpubController _epubController = EpubController(document: EpubDocument.openFile(epubFile));

for (var epubViewChapter in _epubController.tableOfContentsListenable.value) {
      _epubController.jumpTo(index: epubViewChapter.startIndex);
      print("Chapter: ${epubViewChapter.startIndex}, Name: ${epubViewChapter.title} CFI: ${_epubController.generateEpubCfi()}");
}
```

this didn't work and never outputted any of the CFi strings.

Thanks for the help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be referred to the package owner

Comment: the question is not about the package and more about how I can generate CFI strings in dart.